# digital display which shows mileage,mpg,temperature etc has somehow moved to the left as you look at speedo.any advice please

Tags: ford

Digital display moved to left on speedometer I can only see half of it, any advice please. Can only see part of the display.

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? What car is it for a start?

Comment: Showing a photo would help too

Answer (score 1):

There is no "fix" for this other than replacement. If you can find someone to solder in a new display then this is most likely the cheapest way out. Other than that you're looking at replacing the instrument cluster. I've done quite a few of them on Audi clusters and MBZ/BMW displays it's a rather time consuming job and it's very easy for something to go wrong.

Comment: Depending on the model he might be able to take the faceplate off and hot glue it back into place.

Comment: Either way it requires disassembly and competence. If only there was some useful information in the question.